# create react app proxy is not working using a different domain api

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cors

My app is running on localhost: 3000

I am trying to call an API from a different domain "https://redcap-internal.indocresearch.org/api/" inside my app.

I added a proxy in the package.json file of my react app like:

```
"proxy": "https://redcap-internal.indocresearch.org/api/",
```

I am using axios to call the API and my code is like the below:

```
function createRedCapRecordAPI(containerGUID) {
    return axios({
        url: "https://redcap-internal.indocresearch.org/api/",
        method: "POST",
        data: {
            token: REDCAP_TOKEN,
            content: "record",
            format: "json",
            type: "flat",
            overwriteBehavior: "normal",
            forceAutoNumber: false,
            data: [{ record_id: containerGUID }],
        },
    });
};
```

I am still getting an error from the broswer says

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://redcap-internal.indocresearch.org/api/' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy:
```

Anyone knows is there anything wrong?

Comment: Without knowing more about the API protocols relevant to your situation, it would seem that CORS is doing exactly what it is meant to do, namely blocking your cross-origin request; you can learn more about CORS [from this MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS).

Comment: usually, CORS error occurs when trying to fetch data from a server that hasn't specified your domain as an allowed URL. If you do not have access to the server, you can try to use "CORS-ANYWARE" to proxy the requests. https://github.com/Rob--W/cors-anywhere

Answer (score -1):

Allowing cors headers, like `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` and `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` should be added on this `https://redcap-internal.indocresearch.org/api/` domain side. You cannot fix it only on your side